# Not boolean operation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel if I have some boolean operation of the form

```
{=SUM(IF((A1:A8="Google")*(B1:B8="Stanford")+(C1:C8="Columbia"),1,0))}
```

I know that `*` means `AND()` and `+` means `OR()` so that we are searching for ones in columns A and B being "Google" and "Stanford" respectively or those in column C being "Columbia".

But is there a symbol for `NOT()`?

Comment: Excel has ```AND()```, ```OR()```, and ```NOT()``` functions, are these useful to you?

Comment: No. If I replace the inside of the IF with OR(AND(A:A,B:B),C:C) abbreviating the arguments, then it will not work. I am looking for a symbol representing NOT(), if it exists, that I can use in something like the above expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` works as `AND()` and `+` works as `OR()`
because `TRUE` has a value of `1` and `FALSE` has a value of `0`. 
And, since the `NOT()` function turns `TRUE` into `FALSE`
and vice versa (`1`↔`0`),
a simple way of implementing `NOT(x)` arithmetically
is `1-x`.

Unfortunately, that works only for `0` and `1`. 
If you’re using `+` for `OR()`,
and you have two (or more) TRUE conditions combined in an expression,
you will get a value of `2` or greater. 
The good news (which you already know)
is that any non-zero number counts as `TRUE`. 
The bad news is that `1-2` is `-1`, which is non-zero and hence also `TRUE`.

An alternative solution is the logical expression `x=0`,
e.g.,

```
(((A1:A8="Google")*(B1:B8="Stanford")+(C1:C8="Columbia"))=0)
```

If *`x`* is `0`, this logical expression evaluates as `TRUE`. 
If *`x`* is anything other than `0`, the expression evaluates as `FALSE`. 
Thus, `x=0` functions as `NOT(x)`.

Warning: if you combine multiple Boolean (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) values
with `*`, `+`, and `-`, they are converted into integers (numbers);
but if you do a `number=number` test,
you end up with a Boolean.  Thus, you could say something like

```
=SUM((A1:A8="Google")*(B1:B8="Stanford"))
```

(without using `IF()`),
because `Boolean*Boolean` is a number,
but you cannot do

```
=SUM(((A1:A8="Google")*(B1:B8="Stanford"))=0)
```

because `SUM()` does not work on Boolean values.  But you can use it

- in an `IF()`,
- by adding 0 (`+0`), or
- by multiplying by 1 (`*1`).